# Can I use a self signed certificate to encrypt gRPC in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to research this but cant really find an conclusive answer. I can find posts from a year ago that claims this doesn't work in the C# / .NET implementation of grpc.

I have created a self-signed certificate with openssl like so:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 3650
```

I created the credentials:

```
var keyCertPair = new KeyCertificatePair(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\cert.pem"), File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\key.pem"));

var credentials = new SslServerCredentials(new[] { keyCertPair });

var server = new Grpc.Core.Server
 {
      Services = { ServerVersionGrpcService.BindService(serverVersionService).Intercept(exceptionInterceptor) },
      Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", 5001, credentials) }
};

server.Start();
```

But now my service throws an exception

> System.IO.IOException: 'Failed to bind port "localhost:5001"

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have something running already on `5001`? What if you use a different port? Your code works for me.

Comment: I've added my repro (below). The downvotes are part of life unfortunately in Stackoverflow. In this case, it may be a result of your very brief question. For someone familiar with C#, it's probably obvious but, I'm not and it took me a little time to recreate your source. It's a good idea to include more details and then what you did, what you observed and what you tried.

Comment: I suppose so, but i havn't asked alot of questions here so i'm gonna make mistakes, i thought i was clear when i asked if it was still the case that self signed don't work in the c# implementation, i spent hours trying to find an answer. And i'm fine with getting downvotes, but it would be more helpful to be constructive so i can do better next time.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, assuming everything in `${PWD}/app`:

1. Create self-signed cert|key:

```sh
openssl req \
-x509 \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-keyout ./app/localhost.key \
-out ./app/localhost.crt \
-nodes \
-days 365 \
-subj "/CN=localhost"
```

2. Runtime

I'm using `dotnet` in a container:

```sh
GRPC="50052"
docker run \
--rm --interactive --tty \
--volume=${PWD}/app:/app \
--workdir=/app \
--publish=${GRPC}:50051 \
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 \
  bash
```

And:

```sh
dotnet new console

# Optional
dotnet add package Google.Protobuf --version 3.8.0
dotnet add package Grpc --version 2.23.0
dotnet add package Grpc.Core --version 2.23.0
dotnet add package Grpc.Tools --version 2.23.0
```

3. Code

Your code but using the repo's `greet.proto` example:

```cs
using Grpc.Core;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace app {
  public class GreeterService: Greeter.GreeterBase {
    public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(
      HelloRequest request,
      ServerCallContext context
    ) {
      Console.WriteLine("[SayHello] Entered");
      return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply {
        Message = "Hello " + request.Name
      });
    }
  }
  class Program {
    const int Port = 50051;
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var keyCertPair = new KeyCertificatePair(
        File.ReadAllText(@"localhost.crt"),
        File.ReadAllText(@"localhost.key")
      );

      var credentials = new SslServerCredentials(new []{
        keyCertPair
      });

      var server = new Server {
        Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterService()) },
          Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", Port, credentials) }
      };

      server.Start();

      Console.WriteLine("gRPC Server [:" + Port + "]");
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
      Console.ReadKey();

      server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
    }
  }
}
```

And:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="2.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Core" Version="2.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.23.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="greet.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

4. Add `libc-dev`

Per this [comment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet-powerpack/issues/22#issuecomment-729895157)

You'll need to:

```sh
apt update && apt -y install libc-dev
```

5. Test:

```sh
GRPC="50052"

grpcurl \
-insecure \
-cert app/localhost.crt \
-key app/localhost.key \
-proto app/greet.proto \
-d '{"name":"Freddie"}' \
localhost:${GRPC} \
Greeter.SayHello
```

Yields:

```
{
  "message": "Hello Freddie"
}
```

Comment: i managed to solve this finally, i found a powershell script that generated 3 pfx certificate files and also installed them to the certstore where i put the root certificate as trusted, then i created .pem files from the pfx using openssl. One for the certificate and one for private key and loaded these for my KeyCertificatePair and now it works :) Thank you for taking the time to help me!